# How to assign a view's UIUserInterfaceLevel?

Tags: ios, uiview, uitraitcollection

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection/3238085-userinterfacelevel) for `UITraitCollection`'s `userInterfaceLevel` states:

> When you want parts of your UI to stand out from the underlying background, assign the UIUserInterfaceLevel.elevated level to them. For example, the system assigns the UIUserInterfaceLevel.elevated level to alerts and popovers.

How do you do this? If you try `myOverlayView.traitCollection.userInterfaceLevel = .elevated` you get an error "Cannot assign to property: 'userInterfaceLevel' is a get-only property."

I wondered if there's a property `overrideUserInterfaceLevel` similar to `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` but alas there is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### iOS 17+

iOS 17 introduced an API to make it super easy to override any trait collection value, including the user interface level.

`myOverlayView.traitOverrides.userInterfaceLevel = .elevated`

#### iOS 16-

It's not possible to override the `userInterfaceLevel` on a `UITraitCollection`. Attempting to override the `traitCollection` variable in a `UIView` subclass is not supported. Nor is there a way to override the interface level on a `UIView` like you can override the interface style, unfortunately.

There are two APIs to override the trait collection at the view controller level, which `UIView` subviews inherit:

- UIPresentationController's [overrideTraitCollection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipresentationcontroller/1618335-overridetraitcollection)
- UIViewController's [setOverrideTraitCollection(_:forChild:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621406-setoverridetraitcollection)

This must be what the documentation is referring to as alerts and popovers are presentation controllers.

If you're presenting a view controller in a way that looks elevated but the system does not automatically elevate it, you can manually elevate it via:

```
let myViewController = MyViewController()
myViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
myViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
myViewController.presentationController?.overrideTraitCollection = UITraitCollection(userInterfaceLevel: .elevated)
present(myViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you want a view elevated that needs to be a subview in a non-elevated view controller, what you can seemingly do is create a view controller for your desired elevated view, add it as a child, insert its view as a subview, and override the trait collection for the child. This isn't always possible though, such as if you're using an input accessory view you'd like to be elevated.

If you can't actually elevate your view, you could manually color your views (and its subviews) as if they were elevated. To do this, you can resolve the color for a specific trait collection, which should be the view's trait collection with the elevated user interface level trait applied. I created this `UIColor` extension:

```
extension UIColor {
    func elevated(for view: UIView) -> UIColor {
        let elevatedTraitCollection = UITraitCollection(userInterfaceLevel: .elevated)
        return resolvedColor(with: UITraitCollection(traitsFrom: [view.traitCollection, elevatedTraitCollection]))
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
overlayView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground.elevated(for: overlayView)
```

Note this returns a static `UIColor` that will no longer dynamically respond to color appearance changes - for example if they change the user interface style from light to dark mode, the color will not automatically update. You'd need to manually resolve the color again with the changed trait collection like so:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    
    if traitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: previousTraitCollection) {
        //update colors
    }
}
```